# finding and replacing path url using numbers by sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tr

i have one big file contains over 200000 numbers not ordering 
i would like to add url directory 1/2/ to my links depend it on first two numbers ,, for example my file: all.mp3

```
19471.mp3
19472.mp3
28463.mp3
28464.mp3
35437.mp3
35435.mp3
```

expected to look like this

```
http://www.example.com/files/1/9/19471.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/1/9/19472.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/2/8/28463.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/2/8/28464.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/3/5/35437.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/3/5/35435.mp3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sed to do this:

```
$ sed -r 's~(.)(.)~http://www.example.com/files/\1/\2/&~' file
http://www.example.com/files/1/9/19471.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/1/9/19472.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/2/8/28463.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/2/8/28464.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/3/5/35437.mp3
http://www.example.com/files/3/5/35435.mp3
```

Capture the first two characters and use them in the replacement string (`\1` and `\2`). `&` refers to the entire match.

You could make the match a little stricter by using `[0-9]` rather than `.` inside the capture groups if necessary. If your version of sed doesn't support extended regular expressions (the `-r` or `-E` switch), you have to escape the parentheses:

```
$ sed 's~\(.\)\(.\)~http://www.example.com/files/\1/\2/&~' file
```